# JSON in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, podio

I am trying to validate a webhook with Podio (https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/validate-hook-verificated-215241) using google apps script.

Currently I have the following script successfully writing data to a document (after the Podio Post is activated):

```
function doPost(l) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1to3-JzhE27-LK0Zw7hEsdYgiSd7xQq7jjp13m6YwRh0');
  var jstring = Utilities.jsonStringify(l);
  doc.appendParagraph(jstring);
}
```

With the data appearing as follows:

```
{"queryString":null,"parameter":{"hook_id":"38035","code":"a92e06a2","type":"hook.verify"},"contextPath":"","parameters":{"hook_id":["38035"],"code":["a92e06a2"],"type":["hook.verify"]},"contentLength":44}
```

For some reason, google apps script won't let me take this data and access the properties like this:

```
jstring.parameter.code;
```

If I copy the (seemingly) JSON string into a separate script under a new variable, I can then access the data within the JSON.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: JSON is a string.  JavaScript objects are objects.  Are you trying to use JSON as an Object without first parsing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a JavaScript object that you convert to a JSON string, `jstring`.  It is just a string.  If you want to access the properties represented in the string, use the original object, `l`.  Ie, `l.parameter.code`

```
function doPost(l) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1to3-JzhE27-LK0Zw7hEsdYgiSd7xQq7jjp13m6YwRh0');
  var jstring = Utilities.jsonStringify(l);
  doc.appendParagraph(jstring);
  dosomething(l.parameter.code);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gilly, I am getting an error which is suggesting my types are still funky. `code`TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 10, file "Code")`code`

Comment: Actually, that worked! The editor is kicking an error because from its perspective the property is indeed undefined.