# Podio Webhook Verification in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, podio

I have created a Webhook in Podio to my Google Apps Script URL with a doPost function that looks like this:

```
function doPost(e) {

  var DecodedPostData = decodeURIComponent(e.postData.contents).replace(/\+/g‌," ");

  doPostLogData = "POST Data Received:\n" + e.postData.contents + "\n\n" + "DECODED POST DATA:\n" + DecodedPostData;

//GmailApp.sendEmail("me@me.com", "Data", "Triggered");

try { 
var response;

      var formData = {   // Make a POST request with file and script data.
            "code": [e.parameters.code]
          }

          var options = {
            'method' : 'post',
            'payload' : formData,
            'muteHttpExceptions' : true
          }

          response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.podio.com/hook/' + e.parameters.hook_id + '/verify/validate', options);
      GmailApp.sendEmail("me@me.com", "Data", doPostLogData + "\n\n" + e.parameters.code + "\n\n" + e.parameters.hook_id + "\n\n" + response.getContentText());
}
catch (e) {

GmailApp.sendEmail("me@me.com", "Data", e);
}


return;

}
```

I am getting the following e-mail (i.e. as a log of what is happening):

```
POST Data Received:
hook_id=12345&code=abcde&type=hook.verify

DECODED POST DATA:
hook_id=12345&code=abcde&type=hook.verify

abcde

12345

{"error_parameters":{},"error_detail":null,"error_propagate":false,"request":{"url":"http:\/\/api.podio.com\/hook\/12345\/verify\/validate","query_string":"","method":"POST"},"error_description":"No
matching operation could be found. No body was
given.","error":"not_found"}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Someone seemed to ask a similar question here ([JSON in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751153/json-in-google-apps-script)) but I don't think it contained the answer to my question.

Any idea what I'm missing or might be doing wrong? As far as I can tell from [Podio's Documentation](https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/validate-hook-verificated-215241)

Any input is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: 1.Use `e.parameter` instead. 2. Remove`[]` in formData

Comment: Also these might be required. 3. Modify to ``'payload' : JSON.stringify(formData)`` 4. Add ``'contentType': "application/json"`` to ``options``.

Comment: e.parameter.code gave the same output as e.parameters.code so that didn't change anything. Removing the []'s on its own did not fix the problem, rather removing them and making Tanaike's suggested changes worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem I implemented both suggestions from TheMaster and Tanaike. Which were:

1. Use `e.parameter` instead.
2. Remove `[]` in `formData`
3. Modify to `'payload' : JSON.stringify(formData)`
4. Add `'contentType': "application/json"` to options.